# jQuery .next() returing NULL in FF but not in chrome, ie, opera!

Tags: jquery

I have literally spent hours trying to fix this but cant! Like the title sais, the following code works in everything except Firefox!

HTML

```
<div class="bottom">
   <fieldset>
     <ul>
         <li>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="fronts" class="config-inp-cha" value="1"  checked="checked" />
                   Buckets w/ adj headrests 
                   ($<div class="price-config">179.97</div>)
            </label>&nbsp;
         </li>
     </ul>
  </fieldset>
</div><!--bottom-->
```

JavaScript Description: pretty simple, I am grabbing the value of the price-config div in reference to the checked value. This return NaN in firefox, but works in every other browser! PLzzz help

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
 {
    var fronts_price = parseFloat($("input[name=fronts]:checked").next('.price-config').html());
    alert(fronts_price);
});
```

Comment: People often use other tools to evaluate what might be going on.  Please paste in your rendered source, free of PHP markup.  It's a lot easier to use something like jsfiddle.net that way!

Comment: Looks ok to me and did a quick test for you in FF 4.0...it alerts 179.97 as expected.

Comment: i just dont get it! 3.6 is giving the problem, (mac version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `<label>` tag correctly?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: you sir, have made me happier than any other women could ever!! haha but seriosuly, ya turns out the incorrect usage of label was messing with the DOM. cheers!

Comment: [W3 Schools has issues](http://w3fools.com). I recommend Mozilla's [MDC Reference](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label)

Comment: I often don't trust W3 School either, but in this case the info was good enough to address the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just change the div to a span:

http://jsfiddle.net/rdyhE/4/

EDIT: forgot to change the end tag

Comment: thanks thats a pretty nice solution! any idea why this works and not the div?

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the fact that the div is a block element and the span is an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest jQuery, and really any jQuery for that matter, you need to wrap the name attribute in the selector in quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
 {
    var fronts_price = parseFloat($('input[name="fronts"]:checked').next('.price-config').html());
    alert(fronts_price);
});
```

Comment: Do you really? I never use it.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.4.2 I believe, if you don't wrap the attribute, the selector will fail.

Comment: One word attributes work but multiples dont: http://jsfiddle.net/eddiemonge/cpcmz/2/